# PHP: passing Arrays from server to client not working!

Tags: php

The server Contents are server.php:

```
<?php 
$err["foo"]="bar";
?>
```

The client.php

```
<?php
require 'server.php';
echo "<p> Server says: $err['foo']</p>";
?>
```

But,This code works :
The new server Contents are server.php:

```
<?php 
$err["foo"]="bar";
$errAssign=$err["foo"];
?>
```

The client.php

```
<?php
require 'server.php';
echo "<p> Server says: $errAssign</p>";
?>
```

Why am i not able to get the contents of the array from the server ?

Tried the following in the client.php

```
 echo "<p> Server says: $err[\'foo\']</p>";
 echo "<p> Server says: $err[\"foo\"]</p>";
 echo "<p> Server says: $err[foo]</p>";
```

None of which are working!!.. please help !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use braces for array and object access in `"`:

```
echo "<p> Server says: {$err['foo']}</p>";
```

Or if it were an object property/method:

```
echo "<p> Server says: {$err->foo}, {$err->getFoo()}</p>";
```

Comment: Thanks,That did it.. But,i dont understand y my code was not working.none of the tutorials i checked out had flower braces!!..

Answer (score 1):

You could simply say:

```
echo "<p> Server says: ".$err['foo']."</p>";
```

Answer (score 0):

In client.php you must do:

```
<?php
require 'server.php';
echo "<p> Server says:" . $err['foo'] . "</p>";
?>
```

Much better, it must work. Note the "." symbol separator to use with strings.